# How to concat multiple webm files with ffmpeg without getting warnings?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I am trying to concat 6 WebM video file same resolution and same codecs using this command `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy finalvideo.webm` but I am getting multiple warnings and final output have only first video file

mylist.txt

```
file '1.webm'
file '2.webm'
file '3.webm'
file '4.webm'
file '5.webm'
file '6.webm'
```

ffmpeg log

```
  built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)

Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k fps, 1k tbr,
 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
Output #0, webm, to 'finalvideo.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.78.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1k fps
, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[concat @ 0000000000797200] DTS -9223363446920184 < 3900 out of order
DTS -9223363446920184, next:3901000 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -9223363446920184, next:3901000 invalid dropping st:1
[webm @ 00000000029e20e0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will st
op working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
DTS -9223363446920156, next:3902000 st:1 invalid dropping
PTS -9223363446920156, next:3902000 invalid dropping st:1
DTS -9223363446920128, next:3903000 st:1 invalid dropping




[webm @ 00000000029e20e0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in st
ream 0: 4094 >= 0
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
frame=  350 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2436kB time=00:00:04.09 bitrate=4873.8kbits/s speed=11.7x
video:2576kB audio:46kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `-avoid_negative_ts 1` as a possible workaround.

And upgrading your version of ffmpeg may help.

See

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6248

and

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6979

Comment: like this ```ffmpeg -avoid_negative_ts 1  -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy finalvideo.webm
```

Comment: I normally see it near the end: `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 finalvideo.webm`

Comment: it works but one problem why my video audio doesn't have a smooth track

Comment: Could be due to the `-codec: copy`. Try re-encoding (transcoding) and see if that fixed the smoothness issue.

Comment: I really can't understand, do I have to remove copy
 ```ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy finalvideo.webm```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885303/ffmpeg-concat-demuxer-freezes-my-video-frames-while-joining-the-videos

Comment: Yes. Remove `-c copy` to allow ffmpeg to reencode the streams rather than forcing it to copy the encoded streams directly from the various inputs.