# ffmpeg concat demuxer freezes my video frames while joining the videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, codec

I am trying to concat 6 WebM video file same resolution and same codecs using this command `ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy finalvideo.webm` but the resulted video freezes some part ,exactly where the each part concatenated
and yes I am using the latest ffmpeg

resulted video audio spectrum you easily see the video audio freezes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX6WT.gif

mylist.txt

```
file '1.webm'
file '2.webm'
file '3.webm'
file '4.webm'
file '5.webm'
file '6.webm'
```

My log

https://pastebin.com/Rzqr6w3b

Answer (score -3):

This is probably caused by the codec's encoding needing to reset at each join point. Remove the requirement that the codec's be copied and either let ffmpeg reencode it with the default settings or specify a specfic codec and settings of your own to reencode the stream.

Default:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt finalvideo.webm
```

Or choose specific codecs:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis finalvideo.webm
```

Comment: it is not working , same result but this time I lost video quality as well

Comment: Yeah, the quality will go down each time you reencode with a lossy format. You can try -c:v copy and -c:a <your choice> to keep the video quality static. But if re-encoding the audio doesn't solve the stutter there, then it's due to the breaks in the signal between the extant audio streams. If that's the case, the only solution is to find (or make/synthesize) a new source for the complete stream.